# How can I prevent nested placeholders from being wrapped by a bootstrap row tag?

Tags: sxa, placeholders

In our project, we assigned a partial design with a placeholder for stage modules and a placeholder for content modules to each page design.
The rendered markup then looks like this, because the partial design (Partial Design Dynamic Placeholder.cshtml) and the bootstrap body (Bootstrap4Body.cshtml) contain a placeholder.

[image]

Our frontend developers aren't happy with this because two consecutive row tags aren't bootstrap compliant.

Answer (score 9):

My investigation has shown that it can be easily done by configuration. Individual placeholders can be explicitly excluded from wrapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <experienceAccelerator>
            <grid>
                <placeholderWrapper>
                    <excludedPlaceholders>
                        <placeholder>main</placeholder>
                    </excludedPlaceholders>
                </placeholderWrapper>
            </grid>
        </experienceAccelerator>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this behavior in the **Grid Definition** item under `sitecore/System/Settings/Feature/`. There is a field called **Row class** (for the Row Splitter component) and **Row Container class** (for all containers). By default, both of these are set to "*row*", on the Bootstrap grid definition. (Official Sitecore documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-grid-settings.html))